# Как сделать игру на JS?

Tags: javascript, анимация

Как добавить в жалкое подобие игры на JS объект, который будет рандомно по полю появляться, далее моргать и пропадать? Как сделать так?

```js
var Wp, Hp;
var dL = dU = dR = dB = 0;
var L = 123,
 T = 234,
 S = 8,
 nL = false,
 nT = false;

onload = function ()
{
 var CW = document.body.clientWidth;
 Wp = .8 * CW, Hp = .75 * Wp;
 document.getElementById ('pole').style.width = Wp + 'px';
 document.getElementById ('pole').style.height = Hp + 'px';
 document.body.onkeydown = function (ev)
 {
  var e = window.event || ev, K = e.keyCode;
  if (K == 37) dL = -S;
  else if (K == 38) dU = -S; 
  else if (K == 39) dR =  S;
  else if (K == 40) dB =  S;
 }

 document.body.onkeyup = function (ev)
 {
  var e = window.event || ev, K = e.keyCode;
  if (K == 37) dL = 0;
  else if (K == 38) dU = 0; 
  else if (K == 39) dR = 0;
  else if (K == 40) dB = 0;
 }

 function move1 ()
 {
  var p = 'px', O = document.getElementById ('img').style;
  L += dL + dR, T += dU + dB;
  if (L < 0) L = 0;
  if (L > (Wp - 60)) L = Wp - 60;
  if (T < 0) T = 0; 
  if (T > (Hp - 60)) T = Hp - 60;
  O.left = L + p; O.top = T + p;
  setTimeout (move1, 100);
 }

 function coin()
 {
  var B = document.getElementById('coin').style;
  var Lk, Tk;
  B.left = Lk+'px';
  B.top = Tk+'px';
  B.visibility = 'visible';
  setTimeout (B.visibility = 'hidden', 15000);
  setTimeout (coin, 20000);
 }

 coin ();
 move1 ();
}
```

```html
<div id="pole" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; position: relative; background: #e5e5e5; border : 5px solid #000;">
 <div id="img" style="position: absolute; z-index: 999; left: 123px; top: 234px; border-radius : 50%; width : 60px; height : 60px; background : #000;"></div>
 <div id="coin" style="position: absolute; z-index: 99; left: 123px; top: 234px; visibility : hidden; border-radisu : 10%; width : 20px; height : 20px; background : #000;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо, а я сижу пробелы ставлю)

Comment: не очень понятно как именно должна бегать монетка и что вы не можете сделать, если вы предыдущий код сами написали, вот [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Xrgv9/) для тех кто таки решит помочь

Comment: Она должна рандомно появляться по полю. И по прошествии, скажем, 10 секунд она начинает мигать в течении 5 секунд и пропадает. Через две секунды, она снова появляется, опять-же в рандомно выбранном месте.
Я рандомно выбираю иксовую и игрековую координаты (top и left) и к свойству css "монетки" visibility присваиаю значемие visible (по умолчанию hidden) но он не появляется...я прошу всего лишь подсказать мне, где ошибка...а то курсовую скоро сдавать...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Xrgv9/1/ тайминги сами поправьте, и имейте ввиду что код ужасен.

Comment: Не подскажете как его оптимизировать? Извиняюсь, я с javascript дело не имел, мне по нему курсовую дали.

Comment: дело не в оптимизации, а в конструкциях типа `if elseif elseif elseif`, зачем вам и DL и DR ? Почему переменные вообще названы так, что сразу не скажешь чем они занимаются ?

Comment: Delta left, Delta right... изменение положния. Т.к. чтобы вычислить настоящие положение : x+deltaX, где deltaX измение положения.

Comment: да я понимаю как они используются. только объясните мне чем `DR` отличается от `-DL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как-то так, если не исправлять сильно много:

```
      function coin() {
            var B = document.getElementById('coin').style;
            var Lk=Math.random()*Wp, Tk=Math.random()*Hp;
            B.left = Lk + 'px';
            B.top = Tk + 'px';
            B.visibility = 'visible';
            setTimeout(hide, 1500); //через 1.5 секунды начать мигать
            function hide(n) {                
                n=n||10;
                if (n==1) { B.visibility='hidden';setTimeout(coin, 3000;return;} //если мигнули 9 раз, погасить, заказать след coin через 3 секунды и выйти. 
                n--;
                B.visibility = B.visibility=='hidden'?'visible':'hidden';
                setTimeout(function() {hide(n);},100);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ну как, что-бы отслеживать нажатие определенной клавиши...ну да впринципе...можно обратиться левой и верхней дельтой. А как сделать чтобы он как-бы "брался" этот поинт. Мне вроде и до мигания и после, нужно, чтобы при попадании объекта img он исчезал и функция coin снова запускалась. После setTimeout(hide, 1500); я попробовал поставить условие if(Tk == T|| Tk - 40 == T || Lk == L || Lk - 24 == L) {hide(1); coin();}, но ничего не получилось из этого. Дак как-же это сделать?

Comment: тут hide внутри функции, проще новую функцию сделать, которая будет просто скрывать, учитывать это попадание (очки) и запускать coin(); но это все мелочи.